# Python. Двоичная куча

Tags: python

Начал изучать язык питон. Для практики решил реализовать популярные структуры данных. Сижу уже часа 3 с этим вопросом. Элементы в куче сортируются неверно.Алгоритм взят из книги Кормен и Лейзер.

```
class BinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heaplist = [0]
        self.heapsize = 0

    def left(self,i):
        return i*2 + 1

    def right(self,i):
        return i*2 + 2

    def heapify(self,i):
        l = self.left(i)
        r = self.right(i)
        if(l <= self.heapsize and self.heaplist[l] < self.heaplist[i]):
            largest = l
        else:
            largest = i
        if( r <= self.heapsize and self.heaplist[r] < self.heaplist[i]):
            largest = r
        if(largest != i):
            self.heaplist[i], self.heaplist[largest] = self.heaplist[largest], self.heaplist[i]
            self.heapify(largest)


    def buildHeap(self,list):
        self.heaplist = list
        self.heapsize = len(list)
        for i in range(len(list)//2-1):
            self.heapify(i)

    def heapSort(self):
        pass

    def extractMax(self):
        pass

    def getHeap(self):
        return self.heaplist

heap = BinHeap()
heap.buildHeap([9,5,23,2,2,1])
print heap.getHeap()
```

Comment: а почему вы решили что неправильно? Как порядок элементов вы ожидали и какой получился. Учтите что кучу выводить как массив малополезно (это дерево всё же).

Comment: [5, 2, 23, 2, 9, 1] - вывод вот такой. Дочерние узлы должны быть больше чем родитель. Родитель - 1 элемент. Два ребенка - 2 и 3. Третий элемент ведь никак не меньше чем 1. Или я недопонимаю чего то?

Comment: `for i in range(len(list)//2-1):
            self.heapify(i)
` а что именно тут происходит? Я с такой реализацией не сталкивался... Может есть смысл по 1 элементу в кучу добавлять и сразу проталкивать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таки открыл Кормена и самое первое - для удобства(?) в книге индексация начинается с единицы. Из-за этого все индексы необходимо скорректировать - левый, правый,  `heapsize`, последний элемент. И знаки в `heapify` перепутаны. Сложив все вместе и отметив ваши ошибки комментами:

```
class BinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heaplist = []
        self.heapsize = 0

    def left(self, i):
        return i * 2 + 1

    def right(self, i):
        return i * 2 + 2

    def heapify(self, i):
        l = self.left(i)
        r = self.right(i)
        # Знаки
        if l <= self.heapsize and self.heaplist[l] > self.heaplist[i]:
            largest = l
        else:
            largest = i
        # Знаки и последний индекс
        if r <= self.heapsize and self.heaplist[r] > self.heaplist[largest]:
            largest = r
        if largest != i:
            # Обмен значениями явный
            tmp = self.heaplist[i]
            self.heaplist[i] = self.heaplist[largest]
            self.heaplist[largest] = tmp
            self.heapify(largest)

    def buildHeap(self, list):
        self.heaplist = list
        # Из-за того, что у вас в процедуре используется <=, heapsize должен быть строго меньше, чтобы избежать выхода за пределы
        self.heapsize = len(list) - 1
        # Индексы также c середины и до нуля включительно
        for i in range(len(list) // 2, -1, -1):
            print(i)
            self.heapify(i)

    def heapSort(self):
        pass

    def extractMax(self):
        pass

    def getHeap(self):
        return self.heaplist

heap = BinHeap()
heap.buildHeap([0, 0, 9, 5, 23, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 4, 0, 12, -1, 0])
print(heap.getHeap())
```

Результат:

```
 >>> [23, 5, 12, 2, 4, 9, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0]

          23
     5          12
  2     4    9     0
0  2   1 0  0 0  -1 0
```

Требование, чтобы каждый потомок был меньше либо равно родителя выполнено.